# How to deserialize object as single item list?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I need to make a service that allows both next jsons as request body

```
{
    "id": 1,
    ...
    "foo": null
}
```

and

```
{
    "id": [1, 2, 3],
    ...
    "foo": null
}
```

I tried making the model like this

```
public class MyModel
{
    public List<int> Id { get; set; }
    //...
    public string Foo { get; set; }
}
```

which works for the second case, but not for the first one, as an int is not a list of ints.

What can I do to be able to parse both bodies correctly?

Answer (score 0):

You could deserialize into a dynamic object instead.

```
dynamic result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(json);
```

Another approach I'm not sure would work is to make the `Id` property dynamic.

```
public class MyModel 
{ 
   public dynamic Id { get; set; } 
   public string Foo { get; set; } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create Models like the following(Model includes all the properties except id):

```
public class MyModel
    {
        public List<int> id { get; set; }

        public Model model { get; set; }
    }
    public class Model
    {

        //...
        public string foo { get; set; }
    }
```

And ckeck id in requestbody,if id is int type,create a new list and add id to the list.

```
            MyModel myModel = new MyModel();
            myModel.model=JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Model>(jsonResult);
            var mydata = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(jsonResult);
            if (!mydata["id"].ToString().Contains("["))
            {
                myModel.id = new List<int> { Convert.ToInt32(mydata["id"]) };
            }
            else {
                myModel.id = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<int>>(mydata["id"].ToString());
            }
```

result:
[image]
[image]